# How to specify a particular document to be searched in IBM Watson discovery service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

**IBM Watson Discovery service**

I want to get the set of keywords in a **particular document** in a collection using discovery service. I tried the below url:

```
https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment secret key}/collections/{collection secret key}/query?passages=true&count=10&highlight=true&version=2017-11-07
```

But, it is fetching from all documents in that collection. How can I specify a particular document to be searched?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know: The collections can have a lot of documents, so the `query` will search across all your documents inside your collection that you *specified* if you won't put a field id inside the query.

According to the IBM Watson Discovery Expert **@Anish Mathur** you can query for a particular document using a `field query`.

**So something like**

`enviroment/{id envir}/collections/{id coll}/query?query=id:{document_id}`

- See the Official [API Reference for query with WDS](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#query-collection).

Comment: Please, try to see my edit. I talked with one IBM Expert on discovery about your question, and I think this new information will help you! If my answer help, please **mark** the answer according to the [StackOverflow user guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).